# Determine corrupt file of "Data Error (Cyclic redundancy check) on IOException"

Tags: c#, ioexception

Given this code snippet:

```
public IEnumerable<IFileInfo> GetFiles(string searchPattern)
{
    return this.DirectoryInfo
               .GetFiles(searchPattern)
               .Select(fileInfo => new FileInfoWrapper(fileInfo.FullName));
}
```

Suppose that the physical disk have bad sectors. This code is called wrapped into a `try/catch` clause.

```
try
{
    var files = this.GetFiles("*");
    // ...
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // This call writes a new entry on Windows EventLog
    // - The text written is ex.Message plus ex.Stacktrace value in this case.
    new LogEntry((int)GlobalEventLogId.FileIoError, ex)
    {
        Source = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
        EntryType = LogEntryType.Error,
    }.Write(); 
}
```

How can I determine **what** file is corrupt if the code raises `IOException` with text: ***Data Error (Cyclic Rendundancy check)***?

Comment: You never read a file.  It is disk's MFT that is corrupted.  A very serious problem, it belongs on the scrap heap.  If you need to rescue data from the disk drive then ask a question about it at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for your comments. In this case I don't want to rescue data, just identify what files are corrupt and report it when my process (that use this files) has encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify `GetFiles()` to use `yield return` and wrapping the `new FileInfoWrapper()` bit with a try/catch and re-throw with a custom exception. Something like this:

```
foreach(var fileInfo in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(searchPattern))
{
    try
    {
        yield return new FileInfoWrapper(fileInfo.FullName);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new MyException(fileInfo.FullName, ex);
    }
}
```

If you want to stick with LINQ, you could use Microsoft's [Ix-Main](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main/) package which has a `Catch` extension, but I think this makes for some pretty ugly code:

```
this.DirectoryInfo
       .GetFiles(searchPattern)
       .SelectMany(fileInfo =>
           EnumerableEx.Return(fileInfo)
             .Select(fi => new FileInfoWrapper(fi.FullName))
             .Catch<FileInfoWrapper, Exception>(ex =>
                 { throw new MyException(fileInfo.FullName, ex); }));
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, since DirectoryInfo.GetFiles tries to get _all files_ before returning.  You should use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` instead.

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` is definitely preferred for LINQ-to-FS, but I don't think it matters in this situation so I kept the code as close to his as possible. Either way, you would not know which file name caused an exception if it was coming out of `GetFiles`.

Comment: Agreed, however my point was that using `GetFiles`, the exception would occur before the code ever reached your `yield return` whereas using `EnumerateFiles` might just allow some files to be processed before the exception.  But I agree that it would be unlikely that there would be a way to know what the offending filename is.

Comment: I think that is a good idea. I use the `foreach` version, I think that is more clear than using LINQ in this case. Just as a comment... Visual Studio mark as error when you try to `yield` values inside a `try/catch` block.